# MVC6 attribute routing with two parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I've had a look around for this and nothing that pertains to the MVC6 taghelper anchor tag in relation to having an alternative [HttpGet] method that caters for multiple parameters.

Sure you can add multiple parameters to a MVC6 anchor taghelper but how do you process the second option with two parameters using attrubute routing...

I have two [HttpGet] IactionResult methods:

```
    //GET: UserAdmin
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _userAdminService.GetAllUsers("name_desc", false));
    }


    // GET: UserAdmin/name_desc/True
    [HttpGet("Index/{sortValue}&{showDeactivated}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortValue, bool showDeactivated)
    {
        return View(await _userAdminService.GetAllUsers(sortValue, showDeactivated));
    }
```

I have in my view an attempt to go to the second method:

```
<a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortValue="@Model.DisplayName" asp-route-showActivated="@Model.ShowDeActivated">Name: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
```

which renders  to:

```
<a href="/UserAdmin?sortValue=name showActivated=True">Name: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
```

or

```
    localhost.../UserAdmin?sorValue=name&showActivated=True
```

IT never goes to the second method.

What do I need to do to use the second [HttpGet] method with two parameters using the MVC6 anchor taghelper?

EDIT

Also how do you handle the ampersand separating the two parameters in the route attribute...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for ampersand in route template. The idea is that ampersand is used for query string and it will always be applied to any route template. That's why your second action is never called.

For example you can change your route template to 
`[HttpGet("UserAdmin/Index/{sortValue}/{showDeactivated}")]`

Official documentation [link](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering Mike. I am still struggling with this. I placed your suggestion in as an attribute and it still goes to the first Index method (as  above). I then, based on Stephen Walther's article [link](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing) used just [HttpGet("{sortValue}/{showDeactivated}")] on the second method and even though both variables had values it still only went to the first Index method which has no parameters... Whats the route template that will force this to the second method?

Comment: @si2030 what is your controller name?

Comment: My Controller is called "UserAdminController".

Comment: That didnt work either.  Tried your updated solution.. tried using  [HttpGet("UserAdmin/Index/{sortValue}/{showDeactivated}")] and I also tried  [HttpGet("UserAdmin/{sortValue}/{showDeactivated}")] There has to be a way to access the second Index method..

Comment: Had a look at your edit.. did that as well.. must be a way to do this and I suspect its easy.

Comment: @si2030 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4pigeJxCYa3VDltdWVmX0dkbG8/view?usp=sharing

created simple example, please try this, it is working

Comment: Checked it out and yours works. I've tested mine subsequently and its the anchor taghelper that was creating a link that the controller couldnt work with... your link had the correct structure eg "UserAdmin/Index/test/True" while my anchor taghelpers had an ampersand instead of the slash. I can only guess its because of the fact I was using @Model.DisplayName for sortValue.  I have upvoted you for this as its saved me... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't split up your actions in this case. You can just as easily do this in one action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortValue, bool showDeactivated)
{
    var sort = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortValue) ? "name_desc" : sortValue;

    return View(await _userAdminService.GetAllUsers(sort, showDeactivated));
}
```

If the `sortValue` GET parameter is not supplied it will default to  `null`, and if `showDeactivated` is not supplied it will default to `false`.

Comment: This works too... wasnt aware the bool defaults to false. I have voted this up as well.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of ASP.NET Core can handle this:

```
[HttpGet("Index")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromQuery(Name ="sortValue")]string sortValue,[FromQuery(Name ="showDeactivated")] bool showDeactivated)
```