# Passing two parameters as composite primary key to HttpGet Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two issues here. I'm doing .NET core web REST API. (core 2.0). I have a linking table that has primary key consisting of two columns (composite primary key). How can I pass both (two columns) parameters to `[HttpGet]` attribute in order to get data by its database id ? I used `/` character like this post suggested : [MVC6 attribute routing with two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063448/mvc6-attribute-routing-with-two-parameters) but it doesn't work for me. I always get my more general `[HttpGet]` action invoced without any parameters instead of `GetUserPermissionByID()`. `GetUserPermissionByID()` is never invoked.

Second issue is connected with the first one. While creating an object in the same controller in `[HttpPost]` action I'm using `CreatedAtRoute()` method to pass newly created object to client. But how to write it correctly to send it back with composite primary key as ID ?

my code :

**MODEL**

```
public class UserPermission
{
    public int IDUser { get; set; }
    public int IDPermission { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER - GET BY ID**

```
[HttpGet("{idUser}/{idPermission}", Name = "GetUserPermissionByID")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserPermissionByID(int idUser, int idPermission)
{
    try
    {
        var userPermission = _context.UsersPermissions.Where(up => up.IDUser == idUser && up.IDPermission == idPermission).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (userPermission == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            return new ObjectResult(userPermission);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Helpers.ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER - POST**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUnitPermission([FromBody] UserPermission userPermissionToCreate)
{
    if (userPermissionToCreate == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            _context.UsersPermissions.Add(userPermissionToCreate);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetUserPermissionByID", new { id = new { userPermissionToCreate.IDUser, userPermissionToCreate.IDPermission } }, userPermissionToCreate); // it doesn't work 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I always get my more general [HttpGet] action` - please also show routing for that action. + add examples of your request's URLs. Also, have you specified the default routing?

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with composite keys are anything of that sort. It's a simple routing issue. The routing framework *always* short circuits routes. In other words, it finds the first route that satisfies the given URL/parameters, whether or not that's the route you actually intended. You can use named routes and/or explicit route orders to solve a lot of these issues, but given that we have no visibility into what other route may be conflicting with this one, we can't help further than that.

Answer (score 0):

If for example the controller looked like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PermissionController : Controller {

    //Matches GET api/permission/1234/98766
    [HttpGet("{idUser}/{idPermission}", Name = "GetUserPermissionByID")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserPermissionByID(int idUser, int idPermission) {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }

}
```

The `GetUserPermissionByID` would be mapped to URL that is similar to `api/permission/{user id here}/{permission id here}`

To ensure that the parameters are matched to the route template correctly you can also use route constraints to avoid conflicts

```
[HttpGet("{idUser:int}/{idPermission:int}", Name = "GetUserPermissionByID")]
```

Referece [Route Constraint Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-constraint-reference)

Core is also a lot stricter when it comes to telling the framework where to look for and bind to models so consider using binding attributes

```
//Matches GET api/permission/1234/98766
[HttpGet("{idUser:int}/{idPermission:int}", Name = "GetUserPermissionByID")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserPermissionByID([FromQuery]int idUser, [FromQuery]int idPermission) {
    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

Reference [Customize model binding behavior with attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes)

For the second issue, the parameters are not being passed correctly. anonymous objects's properties have to match the target action's parameters in order to map the action.

```
return CreatedAtRoute(
    "GetUserPermissionByID", 
    new { 
        idUser = userPermissionToCreate.IDUser, 
        idPermission = userPermissionToCreate.IDPermission 
    }, 
    userPermissionToCreate
);
```